# How to force the allowed number of values of a custom field to 1

Tags: 8, entities

I'm creating a custom field for a Drupal 8 site. How do I force the field cardinality to be just 1? All the answers I find are for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it:

```
    /**
     * Plugin implementation of the 'comment' field type.
     *
     * @FieldType(
     *   id = "comment",
     *   label = @Translation("Comments"),
     *   description = @Translation("This field manages configuration and presentation of comments on an entity."),
     *   list_class = "\Drupal\comment\CommentFieldItemList",
     *   default_widget = "comment_default",
     *   default_formatter = "comment_default",
     *   cardinality = 1,
     * )
     */
```

It's here: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2403703#comment-12248397